# "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Tags: cordova

I am trying to use [a Barcode scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner) (using 2.0.0 version) in my application, But it fails with the bellow error. I am using android sdk 15.

> [2012-10-08 19:18:33 -
>   Android_ApacheCordovaPluginAndroidApacheCordovaPluginAndroid] Dx 1
>   error; aborting [2012-10-08 19:18:33 -
>   Android_ApacheCordovaPluginAndroidApacheCordovaPluginAndroid]
>   Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: This is asked plenty of times: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1&oq=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+1&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.501j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that IBM Worklight already comes packaged with PhoneGap/Apache Cordova. However, not until this month (Dec 2012), did they upgrade support to PhoneGap 2.2 It may have been an issue with conflicting PhoneGap libraries (embedded one and the one you added in). Check to see how the dependencies are reading and try updating and using the embedded.